# Firebase passwordless sign-in to be only allowed for predefined Firestore users

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

What I am trying to achieve with my Firebase project is the following:

1. **User account is created in the Authentication menu of the Firebase
   console by a system admin**
   [image]
2. **On our Website, the user enters the email which was previously
   provided to us (so, we created it in the cloud console)**
   [image: enter code here]
3. **Entered email is checked whether it is one of the
   predefined emails/accounts that we already have under the Users menu
   of the authentication tab.**

If the email is one of the predefined ones, then we allow the validation to continue. Otherwise, we don't send validation email (So, we don't spam people whose email got eventually abused) and we don't create a new account in the system and we just return 403 error somehow.

On the website, the way we access Firestore is through the firebase-admin package:

```
//admin.js

const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

const db = admin.firestore();

module.exports = { admin, db };
```

So, how can I achieve this behaviour and accomplish it in the most clean and robust way? I've bee using [this repo](https://github.com/HamzaAnwar1998/firebase-authentication/tree/email-link-auth) as a starting point but it has no such restriction on predefined users and whatever email is entered in the form - email is sent to it.

Comment: I'm not clear.  Are you expecting user in Firebase Auth and documents in Firestore to be linked in some way automatically?  Because they aren't at all.  You need to a significant amount of code for that, and it's a level of effort outside that of a Stack Overflow answer.

Comment: I am not expecting anything from Firestore (while sign-in with email is performed). I just expect only predefined Users in the Authenticaton menu on Firebase console to be allowed for paswordless sign-in. Once logged in, I will be making reference to user's identity to query Firestore collections.

Comment: And aren't they allowed?

Comment: @AlexMamo Yes, they are allowed but the problem is that I can use a random email. If I have access to this random email, I can verify my account and authentication passes. I want to avoid that. I want to allow only accounts which are predefined in Authentication/Users on Firebase Console.

Comment: So if I'm clear, the problem here with Auth doesn't actually have anything to do at all with Firestore?  You might want to edit your question to clarify only what's needed (remove all the talk about Firestore and just focus on what you want to do with Auth) to know so there is less confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation on [user self-service](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/users#user-actions):

> By default, Firebase enables users to sign-up and delete their accounts without administrative intervention. In many circumstances, this enables end-users to discover your application or service and onboard (or offboard) with minimal friction.
>
> There are situations, however, where you want users to be manually or programmatically created by an administrator, either using the Admin SDK or Firebase console. In these cases, you can disable user actions from the [Authentication settings](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/authentication/settings) page, which prevents account creation and deletion by end-users. If you are using multi-tenancy, you will need to make an HTTP request to [disable these features](https://firebase.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.tenants/patch) on a per-tenant basis.
>
> If an end-user attempts to create or delete an account within your system, the Firebase service will return an error code: `auth/admin-restricted-operation` for Web API calls, or `ERROR_ADMIN_RESTRICTED_OPERATION` for Android and iOS. You should gracefully handle the error on your front-end by asking the user to take the appropriate actions for your service.

In short: you can nowadays specify whether user can create new accounts from the Firebase console [here](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/authentication/settings)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I was wondering whether this (passwordless sign-in) is the better option over creating a User (email and password) and directly sending a 'reset password' email to this user from the Firebase Console. And then, I would have a regular email/password sign-in experience on the Front-End. I am curious how are access tokens maintained when using passwordless approach? Would it be the same experience as if I was doing regular email/password login?